# How to print 0 - 10000 to file with zeors as padding using Python

Tags: python

I am looking to create a file printing 0 to 10000 with padded zeros

For example:
00001
00002
00003
00004
...
09999
10000

How could I achieve this? Thank you!

Edit, I see that this was marked as duplicate for the leading zeros, my issue is more the printing all numbers out to file. Thanks!!

Comment: `'{:06d}'.format(number)` or `f'{number:06d}'` (for python >= 3.6).

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the following:

```
>>> ns = '4'
>>> print(ns.zfill(5))
00004
```

Full example:

```
for i in range(1, 10001):
    print(str(i).zfill(5))
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using Python 3.6+:

```
print(' '.join(f'{i:06d}' for i in range(1, 10_000 + 1)))
```

For previous versions of Python:

```
print(' '.join('{:06d}'.format(i) for i in range(1, 10_000 + 1)))
```